# Laravel Homestead with Apache server

Tags: laravel, apache, vagrant, homestead

Last year, after being a long time user of a WAMP stack, I switched over to Homestead on Vagrant. For a non-Laravel development project, I am required to use Apache Server. I know that it is possible to install Apache server on Homestead and then add Virtual Hosts for each site, but this seems a bit impractical. The sites in the Homestead.yaml file work with Nginx but don't seem to work with Apache.

My questions are:

- Is there away of creating the Virtual Hosts automatically in Apache?
- Is there another Vagrant box that would do this or that you can
  recommend for use with Apache?
- Am I just missing something?

I'm kind of a noob in these things. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As for now, to make a site entry in Homestead.yaml file works with Apache2, you need to:

1- Add the site to `Homestead.yaml`, with `type: apache` 
as fellow

```
sites:
    -
        map: homestead.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/Laravel/public    
    -
        map: homestead.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/Apache/public
        type: apache
```

2- go to the vagrant box directory, and run

```
vagrant destroy
```

3- then run

```
vagrant up
```

4- shh to the vagrant machine

```
vagrant ssh
```

5- flip the server, by running:

```
flip
```

you'll get this message:

```
nginx stopped
apache started
```

### To test

I've created the directory Apache/public

```
mkdir -p Apache/public
```

then inside it, I've created the file index.php

```
echo "<?php phpinfo();" > Apache/public/index.php
```

Which is accessible using the same IP address of the default homestead negix site

Comment: are you sure it will not be enough to run `$ vagrant reload --provision`?

Comment: last time when I tested, it wasn't necessary to `destroy`/`up` after editing Homestead.yaml. but I'm not sure fore the current version of vagrant

Comment: You are right. It is still needed `destroy / up` I tried both ways last night.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `flip` command doesn't do anything in my case.

Comment: I had to install apache in the box myself then it worked

Comment: Don't forget that ```destroy``` will remove all databases. Back them up first. Later versions of Homestead have an auto backup on destroy. 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#database-backups

It's easy to miss this in the heat of the moment as the `Code` directory is on the 'real' machine.

Answer (score 3):

Add `type: apache` to your homestead.yaml sites configuration, then realod the vagrant machine using `vagrant reload --provision`

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/{path/to/laravel}/public
      type: "apache"
```

[Learn more in laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead#site-types)

Answer (score 2):

I'm still researching and figuring it out myself. The documentation is practically nonexistent, but see https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead#adding-additional-sites

In particular:

> Site Types
>
> Homestead supports several types of sites which allow you to easily
>   run projects that are not based on Laravel. For example, we may easily
>   add a Symfony application to Homestead using the  symfony2 site type:
>
> sites:
>       - map: symfony2.app
>         to: /home/vagrant/Code/Symfony/public
>         type: symfony2 The available site types are: apache, laravel (the default), proxy, silverstripe, statamic, and  symfony2.

Also note: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-and-apache

Will revise as I learn more.